# Function executes but gives a segmentation error, C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote a C function to take a char* as an input and split it using a space and store tokens again in a string array.

My code executes properly but before it finishes the execution, it gives an error saying segmentation error. Can anyone show me what is wrong.

```
void parseCommand(char *msg)
{    
    char buffer[25][30];
    char *tok;
    char *msgCopy;
    //strcpy(msgCopy,msg);
    msgCopy =msg;
    tok = strtok(msgCopy," ");
    strcpy(buffer[0],tok);
    int i=1;
    while(tok != NULL ){

        tok = strtok (NULL, " ");
        strcpy(buffer[i],tok);  //me line eke error eka
        printf("%d : %s\n",i,buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't specify input which causes it to fail. I guess you simply overflow "buffer" with too long strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok` finally returns `NULL` to signal that there are no more tokens and you call `strcpy(buffer[i],tok);` which attempts to read from `NULL`. This causes segfault.

You can solve it by moving `strtok` into loop condition:

```
while((tok = strtok (NULL, " ")) != NULL ){
    strcpy...
```

or escaping loop using `break` statement:

```
while(1){
    tok = strtok (NULL, " ");
    if(tok == NULL) break;
    strcpy...
```

Comment: Note that this could be avoided by using a sanitised `for( tok = strtok(msgCopy," "); tok; tok = strtok (NULL, " ") ) {}` loop. (or even better: avoid strtok() alltogether and using strchr() or strspn() / strcspn() )